# Does Spring's JedisConnectionFactory support the new JedisCluster?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, jedis

We are migrating our Redis stack over to [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec).

In portions of our application, this has meant that we have had to replace the [Jedis](http://javadox.com/redis.clients/jedis/2.6.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html) object with the [JedisCluster](http://javadox.com/redis.clients/jedis/2.6.0/redis/clients/jedis/JedisCluster.html) object.

In our Spring client, we use the [JedisConnectionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html) to persist sessions to redis.  However, this class does not appear to support JedisCluster.

Any thoughts on how one would go about wiring up a Spring application to a Redis Cluster?

I noticed that this factory implements [RedisConnectionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/connection/RedisConnectionFactory.html) which requires an instance of [RedisConnection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/connection/RedisConnection.html) to be returned.  However, this assumes that only one connection to a Redis server would be required, which is not the case in RedisCluster (it takes a set of redis servers and creates connections for all of them).  As a result, I am not sure what interfaces one would need to implement in order to bring Spring into our new stack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Found any answers to this yet?

Comment: Nothing. Nadda. Zilch.

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471666/how-to-config-redis-cluster-when-use-spring-data-redis-1-7-0-m1

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Redis 1.7 will support Redis Cluster using the Jedis and the lettuce driver. Release-Date ETA first of April 2016.

Code samples for Spring Data Redis Cluster are already online: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/redis/cluster

Answer (score -2):

Operate through Sentinel:

```
>     /**  * jedis  */ @Bean public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {   RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig
> = new RedisSentinelConfiguration() .master("mymaster")   .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26379) .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26380);   return
> new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig); }
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel