# How to config redis-cluster when use spring-data-redis 1.7.0.M1

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I use spring-data-redis version 1.7.0.M1,and jedis version 2.8.0
Here is my configuration

```
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hashKeySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hashValueSerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and use 【redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("foo")】 to test

throw the exception

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: MOVED 12182 192.168.1.223:7002; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisMovedDataException: MOVED 12182 192.168.1.223:7002
```

How to config redis-cluster when use spring-data-redis 1.7.0.M1?

Comment: Cluster needs to be configured on `RedisConnectionFactory`. Can you please add the configuration for it. Additionally there's an example project for Redis Cluster available on github in the [spring-data-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/redis/cluster) repository as well as in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/html/#cluster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all that is needed is setting the inital collection of cluster nodes in `RedisClusterConfiguration` and provide that one to `JedisConnectionFactory` or `LettuceConnectionFactory`.

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    List<String> clusterNodes = Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:30001", "127.0.0.1:30002", "127.0.0.1:30003");

    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      return new JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterNodes));
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {

      // just used StringRedisTemplate for simplicity here.
      return new StringRedisTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

Spring Boot will provide configuration properties (`spring.redis.cluster.nodes`, `spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects`) for working with Redis cluster in the next release. 
See [commit/166a27](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/166a27f16c0ff6500090fcec5c69c3e4d79fd8b3) for details.

The [spring-data-examples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/redis/cluster) already contains an example of Spring Data Redis cluster support.